# debugging in VS Studio how to display whole array

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm debugging a C program in VS Studio. I've downloaded and successfully set up MinGw. I'm having an issue where I can't display all the contents of an `int array[4]` in the debug window. my array `A` appears int he debug window. I double click it, but it only shows the first value `10`. Any suggestions appreciated (I tried double clicking it, writing into the debug console `p A` as I would do using GDB, but these don't work).

`

I'm debugging the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void quickSort(int * A, int p, int r);
int partition(int * A, int p, int r);

void quickSort(int * A, int p, int r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, r); // first half
        quickSort(A, q + 1, r); // second half
    }
}

int partition(int * A, int p, int r)
{
    int x = A[r]; // x = key AKA pivot
    int i = p - 1;

    for(int j = p; j <= r-1; j++)
    {
        if(A[j] <= x)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            A[i+1] = A[j];
        }
    }
    A[i+1] = x;
    return i + 1;
}
```

NOTE: Main() is pictured below in the screenshot:
In the attached screenshot below, you see in WATCH that I can only see the first value, 10, but the array contains `{10, 5, 7, 1}`

[image: debug]

Comment: Please show the full code. You have not even shown how `A` is defined. I suspect it is an `int *` in which case it is not an array. In C, when passed to functions arrays decay to pointers. Try looking at `arr` instead which is an actual array.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum. I suspect you're correct --I'll show the additional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not swap the values in the `partition` function at two line:

```
A[i+1] = A[j];

A[i+1] = x
```

You should swap the values by using the swap function:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) 
{ 
    int t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
}
```

then in your code:

```
swap(&A[i], &A[j]); // A[i] not A[i+1] as you did in your code.
swap(&A[i+1], &A[r]);
```

In `quickSort` function, you should change to:

```
quickSort(A, p, q-1); // first half
quickSort(A, q + 1, r); // second half
```

Finally, when you call the `quickSort` function, it should be:

```
quickSort(arr, 0, 3);
```

Because, `4` is out of the array.

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void quickSort(int * A, int p, int r);
int partition(int * A, int p, int r);
void swap(int* a, int* b) 
{ 
    int t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 

void quickSort(int * A, int p, int r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, q-1); // first half
        quickSort(A, q + 1, r); // second half
    }
}

int partition(int * A, int p, int r)
{
    int x = A[r]; // x = key AKA pivot
    int i = p - 1;

    for(int j = p; j <= r-1; j++)
    {
        if(A[j] <= x)
        {
            i = i + 1;
           swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&A[i+1], &A[r]);
    return i + 1;
}

int main () {
    int arr[4] = {10, 5, 7, 1};

    quickSort(arr, 0, 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The output of test:

```
1                                                                                                                       
5                                                                                                                       
7                                                                                                                       
10
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... I'm going to apply this helpful feedback